# Permission Denied When Trying to use --browser in JSTestDriver on OSX 10.6

Tags: javascript, macos, js-test-driver

I started playing around with [JSTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) tonight and got it to work without too many issues.  I attempt use the --browser switch to have it autocapture chrome or firefox on my local system here; however, it always threw an error saying "permission denied".  I attempted to run the command using sudo and still the same thing.

```
java -jar $JSTESTDRIVER_HOME/JsTestDriver-1.3.2.jar --port 4224 --browser /Applications/Firefox.app
```

I can open Firefox using the above path from Terminal so know that the path is valid.

I feel like I'm missing something simple and small.  Has anyone seen this issue and know what I'm missing?

UPDATE 1:
Tried to move Firefox out of the /Applications/ directory and still same issue even running under the super user account (using sudo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my issue.

While /Applications/Firefox.app is what's shown the GUI, the actual executable script for the program is in the /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox file.

Changing the path to the deeper folder resolved the issue.